# Nodejs Order of properties guarantee

Tags: node.js, properties

Note: I am using Nodejs which may or may not have subtle differences from vanilla ECMAscript's standards.

I have always heard that when using a for-each loop to iterate over the properties of an object, I should not count on the properties being in the same order. (even though in practice I have never seen a case where the objects were iterated over in a different order). In production, we have what I believe to be a typo where an object is created with an overwritten property.

```
var obj = {
  a: 'a property',
  b: 'another property',
  c: 'yet another property',
  a: 'woah we have another a?'
}
```

In Nodejs, am I guaranteed that the second a property containing the string `'woah we have another a?'` will **ALWAYS** shadow the first a property containing the string `'a property'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (even though in practice I have never seen a case where the objects were iterated over in a different order)
>   The following should give you a different order in V8 atleast.

```
var obj = {
  "first":"first",
  "2":"2",
  "34":"34",
  "1":"1",
  "second":"second"
};
for (var i in obj) { console.log(i); };
// Order listed:
// "1"
// "2"
// "34"
// "first"
// "second"
```

As discussed [here](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164)

> ECMA-262 does not specify enumeration order. The de facto standard is to match
>   insertion order, which V8 also does, but with one exception:
>
> V8 gives no guarantees on the enumeration order for array indices (i.e., a property
>   name that can be parsed as a 32-bit unsigned integer).
>
> Remembering the insertion order for array indices would incur significant memory
>   overhead.

Though the above says the enumeration order is not specified but that is after the object is created. I think we can safely assume that insertion order should remain consistent, as there is no point for any engine to do otherwise and alter the insertion order.

```
var obj = {
  "first":"first",
  "2":"2",
  "34":"34",
  "1":"1",
  "second":"second",
  2: "two"
};
// gives result
{ '1': '1',
  '2': 'two',
  '34': '34',
  first: 'first',
  second: 'second' }
```