# How can I get the original order of files in the request?

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I'm using express and multer. In the following the files are in a random order. The order of the files is important to this particular request. How can I obtain the original order from the request? All I need is an array of original names.

```
/* POST Put user items. */
router.post('/put', upload.array('useritem'), function (req, res, next) {
    // req.files is always in a different order.
});
```

Comment: Are you certain the request has the order you're expecting? (Use a network monitor for that - wireshark for example). When using the `array` middleware, files are pushed into an array in the order they are parsed. There shouldn't be a reason for that to be different then the order in the request

Comment: I've been using Fiddler 2. The request is always in the same order. When I get it from multer it is in a random order. I want to get the original order from the request itself so that I can sort these files appropriately.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, I always get the files in the order in which they are uploaded (which makes sense; like @Amit says, files are pushed into an array in the order they are parsed). Do you have any other middleware that may be causing this? Have you tried creating an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I have reopened your bug and asked some more questions for you.  We have a test for this that passes so we need to figure out why it doesn't work for you. As @robertklep said, I would need a verifiable example that fails. https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/185

Answer (score -3):

<strike>`Node` doesn't guarantee the index order of arrays. See this question for more info: [Nodejs Order of properties guarantee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927089/nodejs-order-of-properties-guarantee)</strike>

As pointed out emphatically, my statement above is incorrect. The correct statement would have been that you should not relay on the order of **properties** in an object if you have used `JSON.stringify()` to convert the object to JSON and then sent it as the payload of a request.

Although my original statement is apparently incorrect, it **is** a problem I've run into myself — where array values show up in the wrong order on my server — and I solved it like illustrated below. Amit's suggestion in the comments above could be the source of the problem. Specifically that it's your client side javascript that's not originally entering the files in the order you'd expect.

Whatever the cause, you'll have to do some work on the client side to add an 'artificial' index to each file and then pass them through as an array of objects.

So instead of this:

```
var files = ['file1.jpg','file2.jpg','file3.jpg'];
```

You'll need to pass an object to your backend like so:

```
var files = [
  { index : 0, file : 'file1.jpg' },
  { index : 1, file : 'file2.jpg' },
  { index : 2, file : 'file3.jpg' },
];
```

And then you'll need to sort the array of objects once it's received by your backend instance, like so:

```
files.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.index - b.index;
});
```

And then you can loop through the `files` array and do what you will:

```
var justFiles = [];

async.each(files, function(file, iterate){
  justFiles.push(file.file);
  return iterate();
}, function(result){
    console.log(justFiles);
});
```

And the output would be:

```
'file1.jpg','file2.jpg','file3.jpg'
```

Comment: What are you talking about? sorting? `parseFloat` for a number? I wish I could -2

Comment: Settle down. It's just an array.

Comment: I'm sorry if that was overwhelming, but seriously, your answer is full or wrong ideas. I see you stroke out the index statement, that's good, but still  there's no need to sort a sorted array, there's no need to `parseFloat` a number, and all of that has nothing to do with the question. The question is how to make a specific module (multer) behave in a certain way. It's not something that can be resolved by replacing something related to your answer (As far as I understand anyway :-)

Comment: Actually, I was wanting to find the original order of the files in the request so that I can sort what multer gives me.

Comment: @AJB This should work in multer and if it doesn't, there is a bug there. I think it's better to fix it in multer than to introduce this overhead to work around it.

Comment: Probably, but you need to re-read the question, and the comment above. He's looking to guarantee the original order of the files as they were entered into the array and then passed in the request. Then compare them to the array that `multer` has passed. I agree it's a lot of fancy-dancing, but sometimes you gotta do what you gotta do. I implemented this fix months ago to solve a similar problem and I sleep fine at night.

Comment: A client that changes the order of items in an array without explicitly being told to is broken.

Comment: Holy jumpin'. You guys really aren't reading the question, are you?

Comment: @AJB Yes we are, but he isn't uploading `JSON` data to the backend. He is uploading `multipart/form-data` so the concept of passing your array of objects instead of an array of strings is not applicable.